# Converting a C for-loop to a CUDA for-loop

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have this low level for loop I've written in C that a friend suggested I write in CUDA. I've set up my CUDA enviroment and have been looking at the docs, but i'm still struggling with the syntax for what's been well over 2 weeks now. Can anyone help me out? What would this look like in CUDA?

```
float* red = new float [N];
float* green = new float [N];
float* blue = new float [N];

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    // Get row ptr from the color image
    const unsigned char* src = rowptr<unsigned char>(color, 0, y, w);

    // Get row ptrs for the destination channel features
    float* rptr = rowptr<float>(red, 0, y, w);
    float* gptr = rowptr<float>(green, 0, y, w);
    float* bptr = rowptr<float>(blue, 0, y, w);

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        *rptr++ = (float)*src++;
        *gptr++ = (float)*src++;
        *bptr++ = (float)*src++;
    }
}
```

Comment: the loop isn't doing much, basically transferring a bunch of floats from one place to another with essentially no algorithmic processing.  Such an operation is not likely to achieve interesting speedups using the GPU.  If you have other operations to perform, and this is merely the precursor, there might be some sense in it.  Without knowing how rowptr<...> is defined, any answer I could come up with would be speculative.

Comment: You should at least attempt to solve this yourself before asking.  If you have attempted, then provide the CUDA code you wrote and ask questions about why it works. "Port this code for me" questions don't attract helpful answers on SO...

Comment: @Robert, the operation is eminently data parallel; GPUs have much higher memory bandwidth than CPUs; and they can operate concurrently with the CPU. I don't see why this operation wouldn't be a good candidate for GPU acceleration.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware, my answer was predicated on whether or not this code sample represents the complete problem or not.  If it is the complete problem, then copying a bunch of floats from one location in GPU memory to another location in GPU memory will certainly be fast, but the cost to first instantiate that data on the GPU (i.e. copy from host to device, or even just device to host) would outweigh any benefit of GPU memory bandwidth.  As I stated, if there is more to the problem than just this, it might make sense.  Anyway, feel free to post an answer and educate me.

Comment: Can someone at least tell me how to write "float* red = new float [N];" in CUDA?

Comment: Like this: float* red = new float[N];   That may seem like a snide answer but it's perfectly valid in CUDA.  The type of answer you're looking for will depend on how you want to use the data in float[N].  In a single thread?  In multiple threads?  Will it be returned to the host?  Etc.  See my answer for one example of how the  red, green, blue floats might be set up.

Comment: @Robert, given the same assumptions I suspect we would arrive at the same conclusion.  That said, you'd probably be surprised at how effectively a CUDA-optimized version of the packed-to-planar operation would run compared to a CPU implementation.  (An optimized CPU implementation would use SIMD instructions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code.  I don't know if it will really answer your questions.  Probably you will need to learn more about CUDA.  If you can spare the time, taking [this webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cudaintrowebinar.mp4) and [this webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.wmv) from the [nvidia webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) would be 2 hours well spent.  Also the [cuda C programmers manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) is a good readable reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N      256
#define NUMROW   N
#define NUMCOL   N
#define PIXSIZE  3
#define REDOFF   0
#define GREENOFF 1
#define BLUEOFF  2
#define nTPB    16
#define GRNVAL   5
#define REDVAL   7
#define BLUVAL   9

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void kern(const unsigned numrow, const unsigned numcol, const unsigned char* src, float* rptr, float* gptr, float* bptr){

  unsigned idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);
  unsigned idy = threadIdx.y + (blockDim.y*blockIdx.y);
  if ((idx < numcol) && (idy < numrow)){

    rptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)src[(((idy*numcol)+idx)*PIXSIZE)+REDOFF];
    gptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)src[(((idy*numcol)+idx)*PIXSIZE)+GREENOFF];
    bptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)src[(((idy*numcol)+idx)*PIXSIZE)+BLUEOFF];
    }
}

int main (){

  float *h_red, *h_green, *h_blue;
  float *d_red, *d_green, *d_blue;
  unsigned char *h_img, *d_img;

  if ((h_img =(unsigned char*)malloc(NUMROW*NUMCOL*PIXSIZE*sizeof(unsigned char))) == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  if ((h_red =(float*)malloc(NUMROW*NUMCOL*sizeof(float))) == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  if ((h_green =(float*)malloc(NUMROW*NUMCOL*sizeof(float))) == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
  if ((h_blue =(float*)malloc(NUMROW*NUMCOL*sizeof(float))) == 0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}

  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_img, (NUMROW*NUMCOL*PIXSIZE)*sizeof(unsigned char));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc1 fail");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_red, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc2 fail");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_green, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc3 fail");
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_blue, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc4 fail");

  for (int i=0; i<NUMROW*NUMCOL; i++){
    h_img[(i*PIXSIZE)+ REDOFF]   = REDVAL;
    h_img[(i*PIXSIZE)+ GREENOFF] = GRNVAL;
    h_img[(i*PIXSIZE)+ BLUEOFF]  = BLUVAL;
    }

  cudaMemcpy(d_img, h_img, (NUMROW*NUMCOL*PIXSIZE)*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy1 fail");

  dim3 block(nTPB, nTPB);
  dim3 grid(((NUMCOL+nTPB-1)/nTPB),((NUMROW+nTPB-1)/nTPB));
  kern<<<grid,block>>>(NUMROW, NUMCOL, d_img, d_red, d_green, d_blue);
  cudaMemcpy(h_red, d_red, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy2 fail");
  cudaMemcpy(h_green, d_green, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy3 fail");
  cudaMemcpy(h_blue, d_blue, (NUMROW*NUMCOL)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy4 fail");

  for (int i=0; i<(NUMROW*NUMCOL); i++){
    if (h_red[i] != REDVAL) {printf("Red mismatch at offset %d\n", i); return 1;}
    if (h_green[i] != GRNVAL) {printf("Green mismatch at offset %d\n", i); return 1;}
    if (h_blue[i] != BLUVAL) {printf("Blue mismatch at offset %d\n", i); return 1;}
    }
  printf("Success!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In response to a question posed in the comments, here is a modified kernel that shows how to use the rowptr<> template as defined in the comments.  Just replace the kernel code above with this:

```
template <typename T> T* rowptr(T* start, int x, int y, int w) __device__ __host__ { return start + y*w + x; }

__global__ void kern(const unsigned numrow, const unsigned numcol, unsigned char* isrc, float* rptr, float* gptr, float* bptr){


  unsigned idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);
  unsigned idy = threadIdx.y + (blockDim.y*blockIdx.y);
  if ((idx < numcol) && (idy < numrow)){
    unsigned char *src = rowptr<unsigned char>(isrc, (idx*PIXSIZE), idy, (numcol*PIXSIZE));

    rptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)*src++;
    gptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)*src++;
    bptr[(idy*numcol)+idx] = (float)*src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rob, one last thing. This is how rowptr is defined, how would that change the loop?                                                                template <typename T>
T* rowptr(T* start, int x, int y, int w)
{
 return start + y*w + x;
}

Comment: Note that there is no loop anymore, at least not in the device code.  Anyway I've updated the answer with an example of how to use the rowptr<> template in the device code.  Note that I had to modify your template definition slightly to make it usable either in device code or host code.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have a question though, it seems like you aren't allocating the following 3 pointers in the cuda kernel though? float* rptr = rowptr<float>(red, 0, y, w);
float* gptr = rowptr<float>(green, 0, y, w);
float* bptr = rowptr<float>(blue, 0, y, w);

Comment: You could set up rptr, gptr, and bptr in a fashion similar to the way I have set up src in the kernel (derived from isrc).  There is enough information and an example of how to do it, so I think you should be able to modify it that way if you want.  My objective is not to write your code for you, but give you enough syntactical examples so you can figure it out.  Something like this: float *rptr = rowptr<float>(irptr, idx, idy, numcol);

Comment: You're absolutely right. I can take it from here, I just want to know one last thing. What is this? 'rptr[(idy*numcol)+idx]'  is it the way CUDA allocates a pointer array?

Comment: That's just C code.  Nothing particular to CUDA in there. You'll note the construct in the array brackets is very similar to the construct returned by your template rowptr<>: return start + y*w + x;

Comment: I see. I've been working with cuda nonstop since that last question lol. I'm gonna have to bug you again haha. You chose not to write your cuda version as a loop. Why is that? Does CUDA just know to increment the index by itself if you have an if statement?

Comment: The way my code is written (and a common methodology of using GPUs) is that each loop iteration is now carried out by an independent thread. Each iteration of your original for loop(s) is now carried out by independent threads, running on many cores in parallel.  I'm not really going to be able to educate you on this in a sequence of SO comments.  I suggest posting new questions or even better, take the 2 webinars I suggested and familiarize yourself with the C programming guide.

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is a simple for loop, instead of writing CUDA, another option is to check out openACC. This way you only need to add directive to your existing code.

Comment: Can you at least tell me how to write "float* red = new float [N];" in CUDA?